# prevent cleanmgr.exe from deleting tmp files

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler, r, disk-cleanup

I'm running an R shiny app locally on my Windows machine that auto-runs every day using a batch file. I recently ran into an issue lately where the R tmp directory /tmp/RtmpXXXXX is removed and the application fails:

```
Warning in file(open = "w+b", encoding = "UTF-8") :
  cannot open file 
'C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0maCtT\Rf140c40ab30be': No such file 
or directory  # deleted file
Warning in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0maCtT": The system cannot 
find the file specified  # deleted folder
Warning in file(open = "w+") :
  cannot open file 
'C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp0maCtT\Rf140c38044f8': No such file 
or directory
Warning: Error in file: cannot open the connection  # program crashes
Stack trace (innermost first):
    1: runApp
Error : cannot open the connection
```

I ran [procmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and noticed that Disk Cleanup was removing temporary files automatically almost every day, causing the app to crash. I unchecked the settings in the dialog box, but this doesn't seem to have changed anything. Is there any other way to disable `cleanmgr.exe` from running automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by Disk Cleanup you mean the automatic job that is triggered when disk space
is low, than your first priority should be to find out why it is low and
free up some disk space. Windows running out of space is a dangerous condition
that could even damage Windows itself.

To disable this automatically scheduled task :

- Open Task Scheduler
- Drill down to *Task Scheduler Library > Microsoft > Windows*
- Click on `DiskCleanup`
- In the right-hand pane click *Disable*

Another related setting is the Low Disk Space warning that can be disabled as follows:

- Start `regedit`
- Navigate to the key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
- If `Explorer` is missing, right-click `Policies` and choose *New > Key*,
  name it `Explorer` and ensure it is selected
- Right-click in the right pane and choose *New > DWORD (32-bit) Value*
- Name the new entry `NoLowDiskSpaceChecks` and give it the value of `1`
- Click OK and close regedit